# Proving fractional Linear transformation is a group....

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve the following problem:

\begin{align*}
&G=\Bigg\{w=\frac{uz+v}{-\bar{v}z+\bar{u}}\,\,\Bigg|\,\, u,v\in\mathbb{C},|u|^2+|v|^2=1\Bigg\}\\
&G_1=\Bigg\{w=e^{i\frac{\phi_1}{2}}z\,\,\,\Bigg|\,\,0\le\phi_1\le 4\pi\Bigg\}\\
&G_2=\Bigg\{w=\frac{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}z-i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{-i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}z+\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}\,\Bigg|\,\,0\le\theta\le\pi\Bigg\}
\end{align*}

(a) Prove that $(G,\circ)$ is a group, $(G_1,\circ)$ and $(G_2,\circ)$ are its subgroups where $\circ$ is the operation of the composition of functions

(b) Prove that for every $T\in G$ there exists $T_1,T_2\in G_1$ and $T_2\in G_2$ such that $$T(z)=T_1\circ T_2\circ T_3(z)$$

(c) Apply (b) on $T(z)$ defined by the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
1+i && 1-i\\
-1+i && 1-i
\end{bmatrix}

So far I did the following

(a) Proved $(G,\circ)$ is a group, but couldn't prove the subgroup part.

(b) Proved it

(c) Stuck, Couldn't understand the problem that well.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JeanMarie Any help .....